# How can I calculate the expression like (1cm - fontsize)?

Tags: xetex, fontsize, geometry

I want the page number to be 1cm from the upper edge of the sheet. How can i do this? I tried to use the expression (`1cm - \normalsize`), but, as I understand it, it just won’t work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,indentfirst]{extreport}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{left=3cm}
  \geometry{right=1cm}
  \geometry{top=2cm}
  \geometry{bottom=2cm}
  \geometry{headsep=5mm} % (1cm - \normalsize)

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full working MWE and explain what's not working and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean one centimeter from the *upper* edge of the paper?

Comment: @egreg, yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: Maybe `headsep=\dimexpr 1cm-\baselineskip\relax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\dimexpr 1cm - \headheight\relax` should do it.

`\normalsize` sets the font size.

Comment: It doesn't work. As far as I know, `\dimexpr` can only calculate the number and size, not the size and size.

Comment: It doesn't work because `\normalsize` is not a length, it is a macro that sets several things. (Try `latexdef normalsize` form the command prompt)

Answer (score 1):

I sympathize with you having to comply with silly prescriptions.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry,layout}

\begingroup % capture the height of digits
\sbox0{\normalfont0}\global\dimen1=\ht0
\endgroup

\geometry{
  left=3cm,
  right=1cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  headsep=\dimexpr 2cm-1cm-2\dimen1 \relax, % top minus prescribed distance minus twice the height of digits
  headheight=17pt,
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]